# Additional colour transparency categories in ggalluvial

Tags: r, ggplot2, sankey-diagram, ggalluvial

I'm trying to reproduce a mobility flow diagram and don't really know how to add additional colour transparency to the fill argument based on axis2 categories. Or whether that's even the way to go about solving this problem!

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

What I'm trying to achieve:
[Mobility flow diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q9bkT.jpg)

What I have:
[My mobility flow diagram example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aeA9T.png)

Code for my mobility flow diagram example:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggalluvial)

oclass <- c("1st", "1st", "1st", "2nd", "2nd", "2nd", "3rd", "3rd", "3rd")
dclass <- c("1st", "2nd", "3rd", "1st", "2nd", "3rd", "1st", "2nd", "3rd")
Freq  <- c(700, 200, 100, 200, 600, 200, 50, 250, 700)

odclass <- data.frame(oclass, dclass, Freq)

ggplot(odclass, aes(y = Freq, axis1 = oclass, axis2 = dclass)) + 
       geom_alluvium(aes(fill = oclass), width = 1/6, reverse = TRUE) +
       geom_stratum(width = 1/6, alpha = 0, reverse = TRUE, color = "black") +
       geom_text(aes(label = after_stat(stratum)), stat = "stratum", reverse = TRUE, size=5) +
       scale_fill_manual(values = c("darkcyan", "darkgoldenrod2", "mediumorchid")) +
       theme_minimal() +
       theme(axis.title.y = element_blank(), axis.text.y= element_blank(), legend.position = "none", 
             plot.title = element_text(hjust=0.5, size=18), axis.text.x = element_blank())
```

Comment: Depending on what you're trying to emphasize, I think this isn't a bad way to represent the data, but that's a question for a different forum. StackOverflow is more about 'how' than 'if/why' when it comes to statistics and data viz. See below for answer to 'how'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's pretty easy to add what you're after. You just need to map `alpha` to `dclass` and then set the values you want using `scale_alpha_manual()`.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(ggalluvial)
#> Warning: package 'ggalluvial' was built under R version 4.0.4

oclass <- c("1st", "1st", "1st", "2nd", "2nd", "2nd", "3rd", "3rd", "3rd")
dclass <- c("1st", "2nd", "3rd", "1st", "2nd", "3rd", "1st", "2nd", "3rd")
Freq  <- c(700, 200, 100, 200, 600, 200, 50, 250, 700)

odclass <- data.frame(oclass, dclass, Freq)

ggplot(odclass, aes(y = Freq, axis1 = oclass, axis2 = dclass)) + 
  geom_alluvium(aes(fill = oclass, alpha = dclass), width = 1/6, reverse = TRUE) +
  geom_stratum(width = 1/6, alpha = 0, reverse = TRUE, color = "black") +
  geom_text(aes(label = after_stat(stratum)), stat = "stratum", reverse = TRUE, size=5) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("darkcyan", "darkgoldenrod2", "mediumorchid")) +
  scale_alpha_manual(values = c(0.9, 0.7, 0.5)) +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(axis.title.y = element_blank(), axis.text.y= element_blank(), legend.position = "none", 
        plot.title = element_text(hjust=0.5, size=18), axis.text.x = element_blank())
#> Warning in to_lodes_form(data = data, axes = axis_ind, discern =
#> params$discern): Some strata appear at multiple axes.
#> Warning in to_lodes_form(data = data, axes = axis_ind, discern =
#> params$discern): Some strata appear at multiple axes.

#> Warning in to_lodes_form(data = data, axes = axis_ind, discern =
#> params$discern): Some strata appear at multiple axes.
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-03-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Comment: That's fantastic, thanks! I didn't think of that, but now I know.